# Site Stopped working after Changing theme folders

Tags: magento2

I was trying to change the theme of my website - www.sadhagi.com on Godaddy Server and recently uploaded app and pub folder of (free theme) using FileZilla to my Godaddy Server and executed the below two commands using ssh

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

now when i try to login in admin - http://www.sadhagi.com/index.php/wapuiywn

it showing

```
This page isn’t working

www.sadhagi.com is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500
```

Is there anything else i have to do for Change in theme ?? Pl help

Comment: that URL is working fine